# Custom product collection filter doesnt work with Magento 2 elasticsearch ( but work with mysql)

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am using Magento 2  with elastic search enabled. I have a custom filtering of the product collection.

Now, when elastic search is enabled, custom filtering don't work however with MySQL search, it does work.

Any idea what's causing the issue or how elastic search is creating the product collection query?

Comment: have you already tried to launch a full reindex? Once you set ElasticSearch you need to generate all the documents reindexing the catalog.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am facing the same issue. Which version of magento are you on?

Comment: Any solution for that?

Answer (score 14):

Just been through the same fun!  Here is the solution for custom collections layered nav, specifically for Elastic Search;

Create a plugin based on your version;

Elastic Search 5 (built in)

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Client\Elasticsearch">
    <plugin name="pixie_customcollection_elastic_product_index" type="PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Model\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin" />
</type>
```

Elastic Search 6 (built in)

```
<type name="Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Client\Elasticsearch">
    <plugin name="pixie_customcollection_elastic_product_index" type="PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Model\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin" />
</type>
```

Amasty Elastic Search module (third party)

```
 <type name="Amasty\ElasticSearch\Model\Client\Elasticsearch">
    <plugin name="pixie_customcollection_elastic_product_index" type="PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Model\Plugin\ElasticLayerPlugin" />
</type>
```

Then the plugin itself - note the difference;

This version for built in ES 5 or 6;

```
namespace PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Model\Plugin;


class ElasticLayerPlugin
{


protected $cHelper;


public function __construct(
\PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Helper\Search $cHelper
) {
$this->cHelper = $cHelper;
}



public function beforeQuery($subject,$query) {


    // This is where to fetch the entity_id array to filter the Elastic collection with
    $filteredIds   = $this->cHelper->filterCollectionIds();

    if(!$filteredIds || count($filteredIds) < 1)  { 

        return [$query]; 
    }

    // Add the entity_id filter to the Elastic collection
    $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter'] = ['ids' => [ 'values' => $filteredIds]];


    return [$query];

}




}
```

This version for Amasty Elastic Search module;

```
namespace PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Model\Plugin;


class ElasticLayerPlugin
{


protected $cHelper;


public function __construct(
\PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Helper\Search $cHelper
) {
$this->cHelper = $cHelper;
}



public function beforeSearch($subject,$query) {


    // This is where to fetch the entity_id array to filter the Elastic collection with
    $filteredIds   = $this->cHelper->filterCollectionIds();

    if(!$filteredIds || count($filteredIds) < 1)  { 

        return [$query]; 
    }

    // Add the entity_id filter to the Elastic collection
    $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter'] = ['ids' => [ 'values' => $filteredIds]];


    return [$query];

}




}
```

Problem solved :)

Comment: Above provided solution working fine with native Elasticsearch 6, great thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the helper? `\PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Helper\Search`

Comment: @MagentoAaron You need to create a helper file inside create a function which have the product collection with same filters that you applied while overriding product collection for list page then from that helper function return array of product ids.

Comment: @pixiemedia Its working with Elasticsearch 7 too, thanks.

Comment: @pixiemedia Can you share the same for Mirasvit elastic search extension

Comment: @Yogita, pls update the helper file.

Comment: @MagentoAaron, can you share the helper file?

Comment: @Manjunath Did you manage to get it to work? Also, did you manage to get the Helper file?

Comment: @Alyas, No still i am looking for the help

Comment: @Manjunath I'm having the same issue. I'll share back if I could fix.

Comment: @Yogita can you please help with the Helper file?

Comment: I tried with OpenSearch and worked well there.

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

namespace PixieMedia\CustomCollection\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Search extends AbstractHelper
{
     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
       \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection
    )
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
    }


    public function filterCollectionIds()
    {
        $Filterids =[];
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();


        $collection = $this->productCollection->create();

        if (array_key_exists("is_product",$params)) {

             $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                array('attribute' => 'type_id', 'eq' => 'simple'),
                array('attribute' => 'type_id', 'eq' => 'configurable'),
                array('attribute' => 'is_product', 'eq' => '1'),                
                
            ));
              } else if (array_key_exists("is_project",$params)) {


            $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array(                
                array('attribute' => 'type_id', 'eq' => 'grouped'), 
                array('attribute' => 'is_project', 'eq' => '1'),                
       
            ));

        }  
        

        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $Filterids[] =$product->getEntityId();
        }

        return $Filterids;

    }
}
```

Comment: @pixiemedia, is it possible to pass sql query or collection instead of array in $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter']
Ex
 $query['body']['query']['bool']['filter'] = 'select id from products where product ....