# Product collection override but filter not magento in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, product-collection, elasticsearch, magento2.4.1

I have override vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php for custom product collection but now the layer navigation and product count is working wrong, I checked for Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder.php file but this is not exist in M 2.4.1 + elastic search.
I am following this link `https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/apply-custom-conditions-for-product-collection-in-magento-2/`
and `https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Incorrect-product-count-in-layered-navigation-after-overriding/m-p/104534#M5628`

But not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot on this and found below link which helped to resolve the issue for me.

[Custom product collection filter doesnt work with Magento 2 elasticsearch ( but work with mysql)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309419/custom-product-collection-filter-doesnt-work-with-magento-2-elasticsearch-but)

Comment: Hello @Yogita, Please update the Helper file code in this case,