# Magento 2 load custom product colletion via list.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

I want to show the specific products from array via `list.phtml` with pagination.

I referred https://github.com/BssGroup/HelloWorld and wrote the below code in block and controller.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $ids]);
```

But it gives all products when visiting http://localhost/helloworld/index/index page.

What is the best possible way to achieve this in Magento 2?

I am using Magento version 2.4.3-p1.

Comment: One thing I found by get_class() method is in the controller the collection is using Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor class.

But in list.phtml its using Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding one condition to the elasticsearch. I found that one condition was coming from elasticsearch by echoing `getSelect()` method on the collection. And that one condition was creating the problem while adding filter.

For that I followed below answer:

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/313477/28621

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing it first? Same on the code below:

```
<?php
namespace Bss\HelloWorld\Block\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends ListProduct
{
    public function setProductCollection(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $this->_productCollection = $collection;
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $ids = [8360,13125];
        $collection = $this->_productCollection;
        $collection->clear();
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $ids]);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I found that the phtml is using different collection class. Please check  my latest comment. Thanks