# Product Filter Count Showing Wrong Count After Custom Product Collection - Magento Layered Navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, magento2.4.2

I have applied custom filter on product collection to hide certain products from listing page. I have used below event for same

```
<event name="catalog_product_collection_load_after">
    <observer name="abc_productrestriction_collectionfilter" instance="Abc\ProductRestriction\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\CollectionFilter" />
</event>
```

and in the observer, I am removing the product from collection using

```
public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        $productCollection->load();
        foreach($productCollection as $key => $product) {
            if(!$this->isProductAllowed($product))
                $productCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
        }
        $productCollection->getSize();
        $productCollection->load();

        return $this;
    }
```

The products are removed correctly however, the filters and product count is layered navigation is not updated.

I also tried apply collection filter on `Layer.php` file and `CollectionFilter.php` in module

module-catalog
module-catalog-search
module-elastic-search

However, none of them are affecting layered navigation filter. Any help will be appreciated in guiding to filter product in correct way so it is affected at all places.

I also used below solution, and it works however, it doesn't seem to be correct way to do it

[Custom product collection filter doesnt work with Magento 2 elasticsearch ( but work with mysql)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309419/custom-product-collection-filter-doesnt-work-with-magento-2-elasticsearch-but)

Comment: I think you have an architectural issue of your decision about apply restrictions to collection. If you are using ElasticSearch you need to apply restrictions to it and apply restrictions to collection only if you are using collection anywhere else. Can you provide more information about logic in `isProductAllowed`, it may help to proper advice. Call second `load` to collection in your plugin doesn't make sense, and `getSize` returns original count without restriction logic. You are pointed correct link to solution, just try to implement it in correct way.

Comment: I am filtering out certain products from collection based on a particular customer group and product attributes. I am filtering the product collection and removing the products by key based on it. I also tried applying addAttributeToFilter based on SKU's at multiple location. However, at each place the collection gets filtered but not the count

Comment: I suggest to collect restricted products and use them in elasticsearch plugin to exclude with `must_not`. Make sense to restrict product collection on before load and add entity_ids or skus to exclude from result.

Comment: I have done that, but still I don't think that is an idea way. There should be a better way to filter collection along with correct layered navigation filter data

Comment: Can you provide an example with a better way to filter collection? If you are using ElasticSearch as source you are enough to restrict ES query (filtered data will be passed to collection). If you need to restrict collection anywhere else - you need to apply restrictions to collection. From architectural POV - this best way to restrict something.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem with the layered navigation?

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, layer navigation showing wrong count after custom filter.@CamiloTorres @Dexter